# How to integrate Facebook chat into php website or application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, integration, facebook-chat

I want to know about, how to integrate facebook chat into my application,
i did a lot of R&D and read and implement a lot of example but  didn't work.

so please if you have a sure shot idea or application or anything that make it happen please reply on it..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score -3):

You may want to look at the live stream plugin:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/